# Elixir keyword list in function's argument

Tags: elixir

given a function:

```
def foo(a, opts \\ []), do: opts
```

I can call this function this way:

```
foo 1, b: 2
```

I know `b: 2` is the same as `[b: 2]`,
but I can't do that in iex, such as:

```
iex(1) a: 2, b: 2
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: syntax error before: a
```

so I want to know, why the keyword list in function's argument is
different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** this is a grammar parser requirement and there is a syntactic sugar in function calls, letting to omit the brackets. `Keyword`s themselves are the same.

---

The keyword list itself is the same. But Elixir grammar parser must understand your intention to do it’s job. For function call, it adds a syntactic sugar, allowing you to omit brackets around keyword arguments, if and only there is no uncertainty in what was meant:

```
foo(a: 42, b: :hello)
```

would work for:

```
def foo(opts \\ []), do: opts
```

but the snippet below won’t work:

```
a = a: 42, b: :hello
```

In the beginning of the line, in pattern match and/or in an assignment, the grammar parser requires the brackets to understand, where the `Keyword` is terminated.